# Getting variable form custom adapter in another Class

Tags: android

Im capturing click events on Checkboxes inside my ListView that the Adapter builds and building anArrayList that I need to use in the view that initiated the ListView

**HiddenChannelsListAdapter.java**

This is my customAdapater part in getView()

```
public class HiddenChannelsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     public ArrayList<String> slist;


CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_channel);
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {

                if ( isChecked ) {
                    if ( !slist.contains(i.get("id")) )
                    slist.add(i.get("id"));
                } else {
                    for (int j=0;j<slist.size();j++) {
                        if ( slist.get(j) == i.get("id") ) {
                            slist.remove(j);
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }           
        });
```

Now in my class ChannelsDialogPreference.java :

```
 @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        super.onClick(dialog, which);
        if(which == -1) {
           **here I need that slist ArrayList**
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your ChannelsDialogPreference initialize your `slist` arraylist as static and change the Value of slist inside your HiddenChannelsListAdapter  :

**Inside your HiddenChannelsListAdapter :**

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_channel);
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {

                if ( isChecked ) {
                    if ( !slist.contains(i.get("id")) )
                    ChannelsDialogPreference.slist.add(i.get("id"));
                } else {
                    for (int j=0;j<slist.size();j++) {
                        if ( slist.get(j) == i.get("id") ) {
                            ChannelsDialogPreference.slist.remove(j);
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }           
        });
```

**inside your ChannelsDialogPreference class :**

```
    public static ArrayList<String> slist = new ArrayList<String>();
 @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        super.onClick(dialog, which);
        if(which == -1) {
         //Now your can Use your Updated slist  here.
        }
    }
```

Hope it will Help.

Comment: HiddenChannelsListAdapter is a separate java file.

Comment: I got it by declaring slist as static in HiddenChannelsAdapter and then in channelsDialogPreferece doing HiddenChannelsListAdapter.slist.toString()